# How to get the date difference between two date pickers on clicking the second date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I just want to show the date difference between two jquery date pickers. The differnce should be shown on clicking the second date picker. Following is my code.

```
<input type ="text" id="Date">
<input type ="text" id="Date2">

$(function () {

        var select=function(dateStr) {
              var d1 = $('#Date').datepicker('getDate');
              var d2 = $('Date2').datepicker('getDate');
              var diff = 0;
              if (d1 && d2) {
                    diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
              }
              alert(diff);
        }
        $("#Date").datepicker({
               autoclose: true,
               todayHighlight: true,
               onSelect: select
        }).datepicker('update', new Date());
        $("#Date2").datepicker({
               autoclose: true,
               todayHighlight: true,
               onSelect: select
        }).datepicker('update', new Date());
    });
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datepicker's [onSelect event](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) , which triggers when a date is being changed on a `datapicker`.

I also see that you have a typo, , replace `var d2 = $('Date2').datepicker('getDate');`

with `var d2 = $('#Date2').datepicker('getDate');`

Something like this:

```
$("#Date2").datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(value, date) { 
          var d1 = $('#Date').datepicker('getDate');
          var d2 = $('#Date2').datepicker('getDate');
          var diff = 0;
          if (d1 && d2) {
                diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
          }
          alert(diff);
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code will work

```
$("#Date2").bind('change keyup', function() {
            var date1 = $('#Date').datepicker('getDate');
            var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var dayDiff = Math.ceil((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            alert(dayDiff);
        });
```